# D3js Tooltip not generating correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

My bar chart is coming together pretty well. But there are still a couple of tweaks. I'm having issues getting the bar labels aligned correctly & still remain responsive for when extra data is added, etc.

So I decided that I'd get rid of those labels and do a Tooltip on mouse-over instead. But I'm finding that it's not populating the correct data. It only populates it for the Green bars (global). When I mouseover the blue (local) bar, I get the same tooltip, with the value from global.

Seems that it's generating the tooltip for the entire set, rather than an individual bar.

**Issue #1** How do I get it to generate the correct data for individual bar, rather than the entire set?

**Issue #2** How do I have multiple values in the tooltip. You'll see from my Fiddle, that it is currently only specifying the CPC, and not generating data for the Search Volume. Can the tooltips only pull one piece of dynamic data? That doesn't seem right.

**[JSFiddle is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/weXNd/1/)**

```
sets.append("rect")
   .attr("class","local")
.attr("width", xScale.rangeBand()/2)
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.local);
 })
    .attr("x", xScale.rangeBand()/2)
    .attr("height", function(d){
    return h - yScale(d.local);
    })
.attr("fill", colors[0][1])
.on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
    //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
    var xPosition = parseFloat(xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() );
    var yPosition = h / 2;
    //Update Tooltip Position & value
    d3.select("#tooltip")
        .style("left", xPosition + "px")
        .style("top", yPosition + "px")
        .select("#cpcVal")
        .text(d.cpc)
        .select("#volVal")
        .text(d.local);
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
})
.on("mouseout", function() {
    //Remove the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
})
;

sets.append("rect")
    .attr("class","global")
.attr("width", xScale.rangeBand()/2)
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.global);
})
    .attr("height", function(d){
    return h - yScale(d.global);
    })
.attr("fill", colors[1][1])
.on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
    //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
    var xPosition = parseFloat(xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() );
    var yPosition = h / 2;
    //Update Tooltip Position & value
    d3.select("#tooltip")
        .style("left", xPosition + "px")
        .style("top", yPosition + "px")
        .select("#cpcVal")
        .text(d.cpc)
        .select("#volVal")
        .text(d.global);
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
})
.on("mouseout", function() {
    //Remove the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
})
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of both of your issues is in how you set the data to be displayed. You first select an element with a specific ID, set the text and then select another ID. The second selection fails because the element with the second ID is not a child of the element with the first ID. You can easily solve this by calling `d3.select("#tooltip")` again instead of chaining the calls. That is, replace

```
d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")
    .select("#cpcVal")
    .text(d.cpc)
    .select("#volVal")
    .text(d.local);
```

with

```
d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")
    .select("#cpcVal")
    .text(d.cpc);
d3.select("#tooltip")
    .select("#volVal")
    .text(d.local);
```

in both places where it occurs and you should see the correct values appear.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had tried something similar previously. And I'm doing it again, but I still get the same results. -> Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/weXNd/2/

Comment: You forgot the `#` symbol in front of `tooltip` in the second select.

Comment: Haha. oh gosh. Dumb mistakes like that always trip me up. Thanks!